# Reduce values from dynamic HTML fields array to the most compact form

Tags: javascript, forms, lodash

I have an HTML form with dynamic `recipients` field array, where each array item has `name` and `email` fields . Field names are uniquely generated using `[array_name].[item_index].[field_name]` pattern. When I submit form it produces the following JSON:

```
[{
  name: 'recipients.0.name',
  value: 'John'
}, {
  name: recipients.0.email',
  value: 'john@test.com'
},{
  name: 'recipients.1.name',
  value: 'Sam'
}, {
  name: recipients.1.email',
  value: 'sam@test.com'
}]
```

I need to convert it to the most compact form, that will look like this:

```
{
  recipients: [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'john@test.com'
  }, {
    name: 'Sam',
    email: 'sam@test.com'
  }]
}
```

What's the most elegant way to do this? Examples using Lodash are welcome.

**EDIT**: fields names are provided just for example. Solution should work for any names following pattern `[array_name].[item_index].[field_name]`, not only `recipients.[item_index].[field_name]`.

Here is my implementation, which I'm not very satisfied with:

```js
const fields = [{
    name: 'recipients.0.name',
    value: 'John',
  },
  {
    name: 'recipients.0.email',
    value: 'john@test.com',
  },
  {
    name: 'recipients.1.name',
    value: 'Sam',
  },
  {
    name: 'recipients.1.email',
    value: 'sam@test.com',
  },
];

const compactFieldArrays = fields.reduce((result, field) => {
  const [fieldArrayName, fieldArrayItemIndex, fieldName] = field.name.split('.');
  let fieldArray = result[fieldArrayName];

  if (!fieldArray) {
    fieldArray = [];
    result[fieldArrayName] = fieldArray;
  }

  let fieldArrayItem = fieldArray[fieldArrayItemIndex];
  if (fieldArrayItem) {
    fieldArrayItem[fieldName] = field.value;
  } else {
    fieldArrayItem = {
      [fieldName]: field.value,
    };
    fieldArray.push(fieldArrayItem);
  }
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(compactFieldArrays);
```

Comment: You should add your own attempts at solving this to your question as [mcve]s.

Comment: @Andy added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the item by `recipient.{number}.` (using `String.replace()` to remove the field's name). Then map the groups, and convert all field pairs to objects, and merge all group objects together.

```js
const { flow, groupBy, map, merge } = _

const fn = flow(
  arr => groupBy(arr, ({ name }) => name.replace(/[^.]+$/, '')),
  groups => map(groups, (g, k) => merge(...
    map(g, ({ name, value }) => ({ [name.replace(k, '')]: value }))
  ))
)

const data = [{"name":"recipients.0.name","value":"John"},{"name":"recipients.0.email","value":"john@test.com"},{"name":"recipients.1.name","value":"Sam"},{"name":"recipients.1.email","value":"sam@test.com"}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) version that implements the same idea, but converts each group to object with `_.fromPairs()`:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, prop, replace, map, over, fromPairs  } = _

const fn = flow(
  groupBy(flow(prop('name'), replace(/[^.]+$/, ''))),
  map(flow(
    map(flow(
      over([
        flow(prop('name'), replace(/.*\.([^.]+$)/, '$1')),
        prop('value')
      ]),
    )),
    fromPairs
  ))
)

const data = [{"name":"recipients.0.name","value":"John"},{"name":"recipients.0.email","value":"john@test.com"},{"name":"recipients.1.name","value":"Sam"},{"name":"recipients.1.email","value":"sam@test.com"}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: I'm choosing this as an answer. Really like non-FP version. FP version is also cool, but looks a bit complex to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using JS only:

```js
const data = [{"name":"recipients.0.name","value":"John"},{"name":"recipients.0.email","value":"john@test.com"},{"name":"recipients.1.name","value":"Sam"},{"name":"recipients.1.email","value":"sam@test.com"}]

// `reduce` over the array
const out = data.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => {

  // `split` the name on the period, and pop off the key
  // and the recipient id
  const arr = name.split('.');
  const key = arr.pop();
  const recipient = arr.pop();

  // Create either a new object or update the existing
  // object on the accumulator
  acc[recipient] = { ...acc[recipient] || {}, [key]: value };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Comment: `recipients` key shouldn't be hardcoded. This is supposed to be a generic solution.

Comment: Then don't hardcode. The output is precisely what you wanted. @s.ermakovich

Comment: `{ recipients: Object.values(out) };`. This is what I mean by hardcoded. There might be other array names in the collection other than `recipients`, sorry if I didn't make it clear initially. I've updated the question.

Comment: Then don't do that then. I was following your expected output. Change it to something else or nothing at all.

Comment: I upvoted your answer anyway, thanks for the solution.

Comment: The output of my answer now matches everyone elses.

Answer (score 1):

I think mine is the simplest for your specific use-case:

Unknown number of fields with unknown keys

```js
const arr = [{ name: 'recipients.0.name', value: 'John'}, { name: 'recipients.0.email', value: 'john@test.com'},{ name: 'recipients.1.name', value: 'Sam'}, { name: 'recipients.1.email', value: 'sam@test.com'}, { name: 'recipients.1.phone', value: '12345'}]
let recipients = [];
arr.forEach(x => {
  let arr = x.name.split(".");
  let key = arr[2];
  let num = arr[1];
  recipients[num] = recipients[num] || {}
  recipients[num][key]=x.value;
})
console.log(recipients)
```

Known number of fields

```js
const arr = [{ name: 'recipients.0.name', value: 'John'}, { name: 'recipients.0.email', value: 'john@test.com'},{ name: 'recipients.1.name', value: 'Sam'}, { name: 'recipients.1.email', value: 'sam@test.com'}]
let recipients = [];
arr.forEach((x, i) => {
  if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0) recipients.push({"name": x.value});
  else recipients[recipients.length - 1]["email"]  = x.value;
})
console.log(recipients)
```

Comment: it works, but it's too specific. Think of a form where you have a dynamic list of similar items, but fields set for each item might be slightly different. But thanks for the solution.

Comment: @s.ermakovich see my update. Not a lot of work to extend to unknown number of keys